# Why isn't Polka Dot listed for trading on Uniswap?

Tags: exchanges, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, polkadot

Uniswap is the leading decentralized exchange for many ERC20 tokens. DOT is an example of such a token I'm guessing since it's a self-declared complementary extension of the Ethereum ecosystem, so why doesn't DOT appear in the Uniswap App for trading against Ether? It's tradeable on Kraken (centralized exchange), yet not on Uniswap (decentralized exchange), but there's no point in buying DeFi coins like DOT on centralized exchanges now is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniswap only lists tokens created on Ethereum such as ERC-20 tokens. Polkadot is not an ERC20 token. It runs on its own blockchain. :)

Comment: so DOT doesn't really fall into the category, or its motivation is not driven upon, DeFi?

Comment: Which category are you referring to?

Comment: the DeFi category

Comment: No, DeFi can work on polkadot. But the thing is, Uniswap is a DApp built ontop of the Ethereum blockchain. Polkadot is not built ontop of Ethereum, but its own blockchain. Thus, DOT cannot run on Ethereum and thus not on Uniswap.

Comment: Is there going to be a decentralized exhange for Cardano-based tokens instead of ERC-20 tokens?

Comment: Yes, there most likely already is.

Also to note: There is wrapped Polkadot on Ethereum which is a token directly correlated to DOT but just on the Ethereum blockchain. This could be the alternative to trading DOT on Ethereum

Comment: How to load a hot wallet with crypto in an untraceable way? i.e. no ins and outs from Coinbase